# how to solve touch coordinates jumps weird while drag and scale

Tags: android, touch, scale, drag, motionevent

i have relative parent layout and adding custom textview dynamically into it. when i drag(move) and scale my current textview it get weird jumps continuously in both pointer index. how can i solve this issue?

my custom textview as given below:

```
public class VideoTextView extends TextView implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private Context context;

private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mid = new PointF();

private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];

private Paint paint;
private Paint linePaint;

private VideoTextMovement videoTextMovement;
private OperationListener operationListener;

private int widthView, heightView;

private boolean isInEdit;

public VideoTextView(Context context, int widthView, int heightView) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.widthView = widthView;
    this.heightView = heightView;
    videoTextMovement = (VideoTextMovement) context;
    init();
}

public void updateViewWidthHeight(int widthView, int heightView) {
    this.widthView = widthView;
    this.heightView = heightView;
}

private void init() {

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(8);
    paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    linePaint = new Paint();
    linePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    linePaint.setDither(true);
    linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);

//        setTextSize(8f);
    setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int textWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int textHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    int origWidth = textWidth;
    int origHeight = textHeight;

    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG & Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    float transX = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float scaleX = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleY = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    float maxScale = widthView / textWidth;

    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "matrix scale " + scaleX + " " + scaleY + " max scale " + maxScale);

    scaleX = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(scaleX, maxScale));
    scaleY = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(scaleY, maxScale));

    if (scaleX > 1.0f) {
        textWidth = (int) (textWidth + (textWidth * (scaleX - 1.0f)));
    } else if (scaleX < 1.0f) {
        textWidth = (int) (textWidth * scaleX);
    }

    if (scaleY > 1.0f) {
        textHeight = (int) (textHeight + (textHeight * (scaleY - 1.0f)));
    } else if (scaleY < 1.0f) {
        textHeight = (int) (textHeight * scaleY);
    }

    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "original Tx-Ty " + transX + " - " + transY);

    if (transX < 0) {
        transX = 0;
    }
    if (transY < 0) {
        transY = 0;
    }
    if (transX > (widthView - textWidth)) {
        transX = widthView - textWidth;
    }
    if (transY > (heightView - textHeight)) {
        transY = heightView - textHeight;
    }
    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "original w-h " + origWidth + " - " + origHeight + " " + " increased w-h " + textWidth + " - " + textHeight);
    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "diff w-h " + Math.abs(origWidth - textWidth) + " - " + Math.abs(origHeight - textHeight));

    matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = transX;
    matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = transY;
    matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = scaleX;
    matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] = scaleY;

    matrix.setValues(matrixValues);

    setX(transX + (textWidth - origWidth) / 2);
    setY(transY + (textHeight - origHeight) / 2);
    setScaleX(scaleX);
    setScaleY(scaleY);
//        setPivotX(mid.x);
//        setPivotY(mid.y);

    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "translateFactor " + transX + " - " + transY + " scaleFactor " + scaleX + " - " + scaleY);
    videoTextMovement.translateText(getId(), transX, transY, textWidth, textHeight, getTextSize());

    if (isInEdit) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, origHeight, origWidth, origHeight, linePaint);
    }
    canvas.restore();
    Log.e(TAG + " ===", TAG + " onDraw");
}

public void midPoint(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "mid point x-y " + (x / 2) + " " + (y / 2));
    mid.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    Log.e(TAG + " ====", "spacing x-y " + (x * x + y * y));
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

float rawX0;
float rawY0;
float rawX1;
float rawY1;

private void getOriginalLocation(MotionEvent event) {
    int[] location = {0, 0};
    getLocationOnScreen(location);
    rawX0 = event.getX(0) + location[0];
    rawY0 = event.getY(0) + location[1];

    float x = event.getRawX();
    float y = event.getRawY();
    Log.e(TAG + " ===", "actual raw co. " + x + "-" + y);
    Log.e(TAG + " ===", "custom raw co. " + rawX0 + "-" + rawY0);

    rawX1 = event.getX(1) + location[0];
    rawY1 = event.getY(1) + location[1];
}

private float getRawX(MotionEvent event, int pointerIndex) {
    float offset = event.getRawX() - event.getX();
    return event.getX(pointerIndex) + offset;
}

private float getRawY(MotionEvent event, int pointerIndex) {
    float offset = event.getRawY() - event.getY();
    return event.getY(pointerIndex) + offset;
}

public void setInEdit(boolean isInEdit) {
    this.isInEdit = isInEdit;
    invalidate();
}

public void setOperationListener(OperationListener operationListener) {
    this.operationListener = operationListener;
}

private float oldDist;

private final int NONE = -1;
private final int DRAG = 1;
private final int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode = NONE;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    float downX, downY;
    float moveX, moveY;

    switch (event.getAction() & event.getActionMasked()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();

            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(downX, downY);
            mode = DRAG;

            Log.e(TAG + " ===", "Action down X=" + downX + " Y=" + downY);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            oldDist = spacing(event);
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(event);

            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.e(TAG + " ===", "Pointer down");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (mode == DRAG) {
                moveX = event.getX();
                moveY = event.getY();

                float mdX = moveX - start.x;
                float mdY = moveY - start.y;

                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(mdX, mdY);
                invalidate();

                Log.e(TAG + " ===", "draging");
                Log.e(TAG + " ===", "draging x-y rawx-rawy " + event.getX() + "-" + event.getY() + " " + event.getRawX() + "-" + event.getRawY());

            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {

                float newDist = spacing(event);
                float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                Log.e(TAG + " ====", "Zoom scale " + scale);
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale/*, mid.x, mid.y*/);
                invalidate();

                Log.e(TAG + " ===", "scaling");
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.e(TAG + " ===", "Action up, Pointer up");
            break;
    }
    if (operationListener != null) {
        operationListener.onEdit(this);
    }
    return true;
}

public interface OperationListener {
    void onEdit(VideoTextView videoTextview);
}
}
```

I have added my touch listener and all necessary functions that i have used to perform drag and scale event in my code to solve this issue, but every time i get fail to solve.

My Layout XML:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoEditorParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/vidEditorWrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/vidEditor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

can somebody help to solve this kind to problem?

Thanks.

Comment: i didn't used ScaleGestureDetector and GestureDetector because i need to manage all coordinated manually to place text over video and this is my own cusotm class that i have created. and i have tried both this class still my textview get jumping weird when scale and drag.

Comment: you have any other solution to avoid weird jumping of view?

Comment: you are right, but, i cannot set matrix to textview.

Comment: thanks. i will try it.

Comment: i tried canvas.concat() and this works. but it only drag text in its view size but not in whole layout.

Comment: but, i need to make textview wrap_content.

Comment: using padding view cannot gives access to another textview. because i have multiple textview in layout then it covers whole layout. and i tried using margin then textview again jumping weired.

Comment: i just want to move view on layout and view can be multiple with fix boundary. every view has wrap_content LayoutParams. but when i drag it using matrix value using setX() and setY() to textview then it get wired jump. i just want to solve it.

Comment: i updated my question with XML i have added portion of layout that i want to add Textview in RelativeLayout because my xml is too big.

Comment: i am adding textview programmatically in RelativeLayout using VideoTextView class object.